# Square connect API - Navigate back to app

Tags: square-connect

I am able to open Register app from my app on iPad by passing amount.

[image]

Now, when I cancel this by clicking on X at top left, Register app doesn not open back my app.

```
Versions : 
iOS : 10.1.1
Register App : 4.54.1
Xcode : 8.2
```

Any suggestions ? What I am missing ?

Code :

```
if (totalAmount)
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    SCCMoney *amount = [SCCMoney moneyWithAmountCents:9000 currencyCode:@"USD" error:&error];
    if (error)
        return;

    NSURL *const callbackURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myapp-callback://abc"];
    SCCAPIRequest *request = [SCCAPIRequest requestWithCallbackURL:callbackURL
                                                            amount:amount
                                                    userInfoString:@"Info"
                                                        merchantID:nil
                                                             notes:@"Coffee"
                                                        customerID:nil
                                              supportedTenderTypes:SCCAPIRequestTenderTypeAll
                                                 clearsDefaultFees:NO
                                   returnAutomaticallyAfterPayment:YES
                                                             error:&error];

    if (![SCCAPIConnection performRequest:request error:&error])
    {
        DLog(@"Error with Register Payment");
    }
}
```

Callback URL setup :

Xcode

[image]

Square Developer portal

[image]

Comment: Have you set your callback URLs?

Comment: @tristansokol Yes I did. In fact if I dont set callback URL, it wont open the Register app and request object will be nil. So its a required parameter to create request.

Comment: I also check with : https://github.com/square/SquareRegisterSDK-iOS example. Issue is same with it too.

Comment: Can you share some of the relevant code?

Comment: @tristansokol : Please refer edit.

Comment: @tristansokol : For more, I just did one successful transaction of $ 1 after that I signed , I entered email for receipt. And after that Register app showed blank screen !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably haven't registered `myapp-callback://abc` for your application.

If you look at the first step on this page:
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/register-api-ios/

You'll need to add a URL scheme for your app to your `info.plist` like the Hello Charge sample has below, I'm guessing you don't have `myapp-callback://abc` in there and Square Register is unable to switch back to your app. [image: plist example]

Answer (score 0):

OK I got the issue.

URL scheme should be same in `info.plist` and at developer portal.

In my case it was `myapp-callback://abc` in `info.plist` and `myapp-callback` at developer portal.